# Can I use だけ and しか with amounts?

Tags: grammar, counters, particle-しか

When I was learning how to use だけ and しか, I was told that だけ and しか both means "only". But the latter requires the verb to be in the negative form.

For example:

> あの人だけが好きだ。
> I only like that person.
>
> これしか買わない。
> Only buy this.

But out of all the examples I've seen, だけ and しか are only used with nouns or verbs. I never seen it used with amounts.

For example:

> A: これは高いね
> A: This is expensive, isn't it?
>
> B: 全然高くない！１００円**だけ**だよ！
> B: It's not expensive at all! It's **only** 100 yen!

Is that correct? Also, can I use it wih other counter words like 一人 and 三つ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** For example:

> 二人**だけ**が生き残った。 / Only two people survived.
>
> 君が払うのは100円**だけ**でいい。 / You have to pay only 100 yen.
>
> りんごを5個**だけ**買った。 / I bought only 5 apples.
>
> ここには三人**しか**いない。 / There are only three people here.
>
> 今は500円**しか**持っていない。 / I have only 500 yen now.
>
> その話を3割**しか**理解できなかった。 / I could understand only 30% of that story.

But your example sounds unnatural. The better translations are:

> **たった**（の）100円だよ！
>
> 100円（だけ）**しか**かからないよ！
>
> かかるのは100円**だけ**だよ！

I think `100円だけだよ` is not enough for us to infer the subject (the price). So in the second and third examples I added that information by the verb かかる (to cost).

In the first example たった means "only; no more than," which is specific to amounts. By using たった instead of だけ/しか, the subject becomes inferable.

Comment: I can't understand でいい in "君が払うのは100円だけでいい".  Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @Dav7n Well, AはBでいい means "It's OK/enough if A is B." 　 So, the verbatim translation is "It's enough if what you pay is only 100 yen."